# fatal error: SDL_Image.h: No such file or directory on VS Code windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sdl, sdl-2

I've been trying to setup SDL_image to load PNG's but it isnt working. Im on VS Code and I can't figure it out.

I've installed SDL2_image_devel_2.82-VC. Then I followed a tutorial that had me copy the contents of the include and lib file from SDL2_image to my SDL2 folder's corresponding include and lib.

My SDL2 folder though didn't have those files, instead, I had a x86_64-w64-mingw32 and a i686-w64-mingw32 files which had in them a SDL2 file which had an include and lib files, so I copy pasted in both.

Then it said to include SDL2_image in dependencies, so I did in my Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ -I src\include -L src\lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

Lazyfoo's tutorial had more steps, such as putting SDL2_image in your include path, but they were made for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code,and my include path's are  all put in my settings.json and in Lazyfoo they were complete paths while mine seemed to start at the project file (like one path was just src/include).
settings.json include paths:

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "src/include"
    ]
```

It also asked me to put the path to SDL2_image in the environment variables. This has me confused though, what was the point of copy pasting the contents of SDL2_image to SDL2 if Im still linking everything to SDL2_image? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The official VSCode MinGW documentation tells you to install MinGW using msys2: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) after you do that you can use `pacman` to [install sdl](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2?repo=ucrt64) and not have to deal with include or library paths. You will still have to link to the libraries.

Comment: *"I've installed SDL2_image_devel_2.82-VC"* Wrong, "VC" means it's for Visual Studio. There must be a MinGW version somewhere. But I second drescherjm, you should just install everything from MSYS2: the compiler, SDL2, SDL2_image...

Comment: *"Lazyfoo's tutorial ... were made for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code"* Your compiler is MinGW. Lazyfoo has instructions for it too. You using VSC doesn't really matter, you don't need VSC-specific tutorials. You can learn to compile directly from the console first, and then just paste the same commands into VSC.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see, firstly I don't think I can do what drescherjm suggested as pacman seems to be for Linux? Although, the VC thing might be correct and I should install one for MinGW instead, I will try that thank you, do you think though after I proceed I should just copy paste the incllude and lib contents like I did before but with that file instead and it'd work?

Comment: [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) has a version of pacman for Windows. *"I should just copy paste the incllude and lib contents"* It's up to you. I wouldn't merge the folders (to make it easier to update SDL2_image later), and would just use `-I` twice to point to both directories.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I used msys2 to install SDL2_image but instead of installing a folder it just seems to put SDL_image in my include and the lib files, the same things I did. My theories were that it just saw them and called it a day, but when I tried undoing what I did using pacman -R and uninstalling them manually, and then reinstalling using pacman -S, it just put them back. Then there is an SDL_image.h file in my SDL2 include, but the compiler still can't find it when I write #include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

Comment: *"instead of installing a folder"* What does this mean? *"seems to put SDL_image in my include and the lib files"* No, it always puts stuff only in `C:\msys64` or whatever the installation dir is. *"My theories were that it just saw them and called it a day"* I don't understand what you're trying to say. *"the compiler still can't find it when I write #include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>"* What compiler is this? The MSYS2 one? It should be able to.

Comment: Overall, MSYS2 does work out of the box. If it doesn't, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yo actually, no need to help me anymore thank you so much for the guidance, I found the issue. It's called me being dumb. My includePath was linking to a src folder that had in it an include and a lib with all the files, and I was constantly modifying some SDL folder on other places, but since it wasnt the right SDL folder it didnt matter. Thank you, Im new to stackoverflow im trying to find a way to give a like or something but I cant xD

Comment: You're welcome. :) You could mark the question as solved only if somebody posted an "answer" rather than just comments.